# Delete all folders except.... (*.BAT)

Tags: batch-file, delete-directory

I would like to delete all folders except MYFOLDER found in a parent directory but I cant get it done?

```
for %%i in ("C:\Parent") do if not "%%i"=="MYFOLDER" del /f /q "%%i
```

could somebody please check the code?

(I'm using *.bat)

Comment: Please check http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/fb007a7f-9207-4dc6-ba50-0723c89e6f77/delete-except-certian-files?forum=ITCG

Comment: Do you like to delete files or folders? If you want to delete folders, should use RD instead DEL.

Answer (score 4):

This should help you:

```
for /d %%i in ("C:\Parent\*") do if /i not "%%~nxi"=="MYFOLDER" del /s /q "%%i"
```

Comment: Can you explain what `%%~nxi` stands for? It doesn't work for me, but `%%i` does.

Comment: rd for folder i guess.

Answer (score 0):

`Dir` all folders and check one by one if it is not **MYFOLDER**, if is not - delete it.
Please remove `echo` when running the real job.

```
for /d %%i in (C:\Parent\*) do (
    if /i "%%i" NEQ ".exe" echo rd /S /Q %%i
)
```

Comment: Note that you spare yourself a lot of pain if you just use `for /d` instead of iterating over `dir` output with `for /f`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, should be /F.

Answer (score 0):

Or simply copy MYFOLDER to a temp folder, delete all files, and copy back MYFOLDER. Unless MYFOLDER is huge and takes time to copy, this should work just as good.